# Form action error

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a user login system using CodeIgniter. Here's the form code(login view) below:

```
<?php
    echo form_open('main/login_validation');

    echo validation_errors();

    echo "<p>Email<br/>";
    echo form_input('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    echo "</p><br/>";

    echo "<p>Password<br/>";
    echo form_password('password');
    echo "</p><br/>";

    echo "<p>";
    echo form_submit('login_submit', 'login');
    echo "</p>";

    echo form_close();          
?>
```

When I view the source from the browser, I get

```
"form action="http://site.com/beta/?main/login_validation" method="post"  "
```

As you can see, I'm getting a question mark "`?`" after `beta/`.

This is affecting further procedure as well, i.e, it gets redirected to `site.com/beta/?main/login_validation` which doesn't validate the data at all.

Comment: What is your `base_url` set as in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: Its set to nothing
$config['base_url']= '';

Comment: Your `base_url` [should be set to something](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/index.html). The `form_open` function uses this value, so if it is missing, then it could be causing the error. Trying setting it to the URL to your CodeIgniter root, with a trailing slash. Currently CodeIgniter is trying to guess this (and is getting it wrong)!

Comment: I had set the uri_protocol to $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"; to use mod_rewrite. I changed Request_URI to AUTO and modified my .htaccess. Now it works. Though i still can't figure out why mod  rewrite doesn't work on subdomains. Thanks for ur help.!

Comment: No worries - I suppose making that change has helped CodeIgniter guess the URL correctly. Although, I would still recommend setting the `base_url`. It might take a bit of time to change if you're switching domains etc. but it seems to be a lot more reliable from my experience, as CodeIgniter doesn't always guess the value correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`form_open`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) function uses the value of `base_url`, located in `application/config/config.php`. It appears that your `base_url` is not set correctly or set at all. The `base_url` value should be set as part of the [installation process](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/index.html). If it isn't set, then CodeIgniter will guess the correct value:

> If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain
>   and path to your installation.

---

To set the `base_url`: open `application/config/config.php` and enter the `base_url` value for your site. The value to enter will usually be where your `index.php` file is located, with the *trailing slash*:

> URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
>   WITH a trailing slash

For example:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yoursite.com/';
```